# IOS. UITabBarController with navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I had a viewController which contains video view and UITabBarController. UITabBarController contains 3 viewControllers with UINavigationController. The problem is that the frame of first UINavigationController is good (0,20,width,height), but the other two navigationController has wrong frame (0,0,width,height). Status bar is showing, so I don't know what's wrong with them.

Here i create TabBarController :

```
    @interface EEMenuTBC ()
@end

@implementation EEMenuTBC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EEFavoritesVC *favotiteVC = [[EEFavoritesVC alloc] initWithNibAsClassName];
    UINavigationController *favotiteNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favotiteVC];
    [favotiteVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritesMenuDisabled"]];
    [favotiteVC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Favourites"];

    EESearchTVC *searchVC = [[EESearchTVC alloc] initWithNibAsClassName];
    UINavigationController *searchNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchVC];
    [searchVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchMenuDisabled"]];
    [searchVC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Search"];

    EESettingsTVC *settingsVC = [[EESettingsTVC alloc] initWithNibAsClassName];
    UINavigationController *settingsNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];
    [settingsVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingsMenuDisabled"]];
    [settingsVC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Settings"];

    self.viewControllers = @[favotiteNC, searchNC, settingsNC];

    self.tabBar.items[0].selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"favoritesMenuEnabled"];
    self.tabBar.items[1].selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"searchMenuEnabled"];
    self.tabBar.items[2].selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"settingsMenuEnabled"];

    for(UIView *temp in self.tabBar.subviews) {
        [temp setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    }
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)goToRootVC {
    if (_delegateMenuTBC && [_delegateMenuTBC respondsToSelector:@selector(EEMenuTBCDelegateGoToRootVC)]) {
        [_delegateMenuTBC EEMenuTBCDelegateGoToRootVC];
    }
}

@end
```

In other ViewController i doing

```
_menuTBC = [[EEMenuTBC alloc] initWithNibName:@"EEMenuTBC" bundle:nil];
    _menuTBC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

And in favotiteVC  navigation look's good, and all other's 2 navigations has no spacing from status bar

P.S 
First of all, I added my UITabBarController as a child to UIViewController. The first UINavigationController from UITabBarController has right frame (0,20,width,height) , but others 2 UINavigationsControllers, has wrong frame (0,0,width, height).  I think they don't have status bar, and I checked that method -prefersStatusBarHidden isn't call from all UIViewControllers which contains in UITabBarController

Comment: Show the code you're having trouble with...?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question.. Explain better

Comment: please share a image of what you are facing with your current code

Comment: what u have consider the UINavigationController frame. Will you please explore it more.. because we can not getting you

Comment: I added some exemple